# Constructing a multiline string from array in python

Tags: python, string, multilinestring

I am currently working on a script which sends out the list of defaulters to a distro. I have the values in python list like this `['person1@email.com','person2@email.com','person3@email.com']` 
I need to form a multiline string from the above array like this

```
""" 1. person1@email.com
    2. person2@email.com
    3. person3@email.com"""
```

I tried this

```
defaultersList = ['person1@email.com','person2@email.com','person3@email.com']  
multilineStr = ""

for item in defaultersList:
  multilineStr = multilineStr + '\n' + item
```

but out put doesnt come how I expected it to come. Its coming in single line with \n character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for:

```
"\n".join(["{0}. {1}".format(i+1, person) for i, person in enumerate(defaultersList)])
```

Of course, the `"\n"` token will be in the string, but if you call `print`, you'll see a multiline string.

`"\n"` is how a newline is represented in Python (and computers in general).

Comment: I am not printing the string instead it will be email body like this msg = MIMEText("""this is the body of the email""")  ... sure \n ill give a new line?

Comment: Alternative suggestion: `"".join(starmap("{0}. {1}\n".format, enumerate(defaultersList, 1)))` (with `starmap()` from `itertools`).

Comment: I am not printing the string instead it will be email body like this msg = MIMEText("""this is the body of the email""") ... sure \n ill give a new line?